# Change the colour of a StaticText, wxPython

Tags: wxpython, static-text

I need to make a StaticText red, what should I use?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here it is

```
import wx

app=wx.PySimpleApp()
frame=wx.Frame(None)
text=wx.StaticText(frame, label="Colored text")
text.SetForegroundColour((255,0,0)) # set text color
text.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,255)) # set text back color
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which color you would need to set, look into `SetForegroundColour()` or `SetBackgroundColour()` method.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
text.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
```

If you are using it inside the panel or frame's class then:

```
self.text.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
```

`wx.Colour` takes RGB values which can be used for different colours.